# Regex Match String WIth Repeating Characters

Tags: regex

I am looking to use regex to match a string that has multiple instances of the same text.  So for instance in this example:

Some text goes here 357313 More text goes here 654321

Some text goes here 123456 More text goes here 123456

Some text goes here 123456 More text goes here 654321

I would want it to match the second option and not the first and third options.  I am fairly new to regex but have spent hours looking online to try and figure out if there is a solution to this problem.  The strings are not known in order to use them in the search, I need to use regex to figure out if they match or not.

Any help or assistance would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain why the first and third lines should not be matched? Both have repeated text: "text goes here".

Comment: Good point, the text does repeat in these areas but the only thing that separates the strings I need are that the numbered strings match.

Answer (score 1):

this matches a line like

[some characters][some digits][some chracters][the same digits as before][some characters]

`/.+(\d+).+$1.+/`

is that what you are searching for?

edit:

`/[^\d]+(\d+)[^\d]+$1[^\d]+/`

to make shure the [some characters] are no digits

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for!  Had to use \1 to recall the pattern later in the search, but it appears to be finding the correct entries.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want something like the following, where it assumes you want one or more matches of some text followed by your unique string.

/^(.+123456){1,}$/

I just realized you may actually be looking to find strings that contain the same sequence of characters more than once. This doesn't really seem like a problem fit for regex to me. While it may be possible to the more advanced regex users I would say that it may not be a good idea to write such a complicated regex. I would refer you to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem which may have information that would apply here.

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I do not know what the search pattern is, I just know that the fields I want are the ones with the matching strings.  I believe you are correct and this may not be something that regex can handle.